# How to execute ffmpeg from with Batch For Loop

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, ffmpeg, scripting

```
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO ffmpeg -y -i %%A -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le "%%~dpA%%~nA.mov"
```

This batch file is intended to take multiple files which are dragged and dropped onto it, and transcode them with ffmpeg. The command results in a whole bunch of prinouts that are similar to the command, but it does not execute. I have also tried using start cmd.exe /c, but that causes numerous windows to open which necessitates a computer reboot.

Edit: squashman has made it clear that this solution would not work anyway (Thanks!). However, I have edited the script to act on only a single file at once and it still does not execute as intended and causes a looping printout.

```
ffmpeg -y -i %%1 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le "%%~dp1%%~n1.mov"
```

How can I modify this script to execute ffmpeg properly?

Edit 2: Resolved by dragging and dropping a folder onto the batch script.

```
cd /d %1
md output
FOR /F %%A IN ('dir /B %1') do ffmpeg -y -i %%A -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le "output/%%~nA.mov"
pause
```

Comment: You could start by showing us exactly the content of `%*`. Just add a line above your posted code, `@Echo "%*">"%~dp0output.log"`, run your code,then post the content of `output.log` here, as an edit to your question.

Comment: When you drag and drop files onto a batch file it sends the whole file path plus any quotes needed to protect spaces in the file path. There is a 8,191 byte command line limitation.  You could easily max that out with a couple dozen files in a long path.

Comment: You need to change, `%%1` and `%%~dp1%%~n1.mov` to `%1` and `%~dp1%~n1.mov`, _although the latter would be better as `%~dpn1.mov`_.

Comment: Your second edit is also incorrect, use `CD /D "%~1" 2>NUL || Exit /B 1` instead of `cd /d %1`, then `For /F "EOL=| Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B /A:-D')` instead of `FOR /F %%A IN ('dir /B %1')` and finally `FFmpeg -y -i "%%A"` instead of `ffmpeg -y -i %%A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expect all .mov files reside in current directory. if not, prepend path into both of "*.mov" and "%%~A.mov".

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%A IN ('dir /B *.mov') do ffmpeg -y -i %%A -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le "%%~A.mov"
```

another way is to use PPX http://www.pirosa.co.uk/demo/wxargs/wxargs.html and speed-up whole process by utilizing all CPU cores

```
dir /b *.%required_file_extension% |ppx2 -P 4 -L 1 ffmpeg -y -i %%A -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -c:a pcm_s16le "{}.mov"
```

Comment: Thank you. I came up with a solution based on this to drag and drop a folder onto the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Worth also considering using a build system like SCons.

I've coded up something similar here to transcode a directory's worth of video files all at once from the command-line:

https://github.com/nuket/Shrinkr#shrinkr-batch-transcode-scons-edition

Benefit of a build system is it tracks which source files have changed, so you can interrupt and re-run the batch transcode and it won't repeat already-completed work.