# How do I convert a whole folder worth of clips from webm to mp4?

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, mp4, webm

For the record I do not know much about code or scripting so hopefully my question makes sense. So I have a bunch of HDR clips from my PS5 saved on a USB, I've managed to find a script to use on powershell to convert a clip from webm to mp4, only issue is I have to do this manually one by one.

This is the script I found:
**ffmpeg -i S127.webm -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -preset slower S127.mp4**

(the file name being S127 in this case) I was wondering if there is a script I can use to convert all clips in a folder at once (or preferably one by one) so I can let my computer do all the converting while I am away rather than having to do this one by one?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Have a look at the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and  [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlets.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310563/how-to-execute-ffmpeg-from-with-batch-for-loop